# Datables add rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with the Plugin Datatables and I am thoroughly confused.

I define my table:

```
GuestDataTable = $('#GuestTable').DataTable( {
   "columnDefs": [
        { "title": "Titel", "targets": 0 },
        { "title": "Person", "targets": 1 },
        { "title": "An-/Abgemeldet", "targets": 2 },
        { "title": "Gastgeber", "targets": 3 },
        { "title": "An-/Abmeldedatum", "targets": 4 }
        ],

        data: data,
        columns: [
             { data: 'academic_title' },
             { data: 'person' },
             { data: 'participated_logo' },
             { data: 'fullname' },
             { data: 'answer_sent_formatted' }
             ]
});
```

Later I need to clear it out and fill up with new content but it wont work

```
GuestDataTable.clear().draw();

GuestDataTable.rows.add([{
    "Titel" : "Please", 
    "Person" : "work",
    "An-/Abgemeldet" : "already",
    "Gastgeber" : "oh",
    "An-/Abmeldedatum" : "please"
    }]).draw();
```

Well if I try this I get the error: `"DataTables warning: table id=GuestTable - Requested unknown parameter 'academic_title' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"`

After extensive googling it seems I somehow need to convert the string because in the initialization Im telling the table to expect objects.

I am at the end of my wits here. Does anybody know how I would accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, what I was thinking is you have to pass the parameter like below

```
GuestDataTable.rows.add([{
    "academic_title" : "Please", 
    "Person" : "work",
    "participated_logo" : "already",
    "fullname" : "oh",
    "Aanswer_sent_formatted" : "please"
    }]).draw();
```

Or

Correct your data table columns array property according to your JSON. see below

```
GuestDataTable = $('#GuestTable').DataTable( {
        data: data,
        columns: [
             { data: 'Titel' },
             { data: 'Person' },
             { data: 'An-/Abgemeldet' },
             { data: 'Gastgeber' },
             { data: 'An-/Abmeldedatum' }
             ]
});
```

Comment: Oh Jesus Christ THANK YOU! The world of webdesign can be hard sometimes, and I realize Im not supposed to use SO as my personal debugging site, but after spending 8 hours on this, I was desperate. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: We are all have sleepless nights for a silly thing. Happy coding